# Centralizers of automorphisms in finite simple groups (reference request)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classification

I would like to have a precise version of the following statement and, if possible, a reference to such a statement in some standard book.

> **Claim 1**: *Let $G$ be a finite simple non abelian group with an
> automorphism $\alpha$ of coprime order. Then the centralizer
> $C:= C_G(\alpha)$ of $\alpha$ in $G$ involves a group of the same
> type.*

I have seen this statement, or minor variations on it, in the literature more than once, but always without further clarification. I can mention that classification gives us a precise description of the automorphism groups of the finite simple groups. This description immediately implies that the group must be of Lie type and that $\alpha$ must be a (conjugate) of a field automorphism. I therefore suspect that essentially the following is meant:

> **Claim** 2: *Suppose that $G$ is a finite simple group **of Lie of type**. Then there is a normal subgroup $B$ of a subgroup $A$ of $C$ such that the **not necessarily simple** section $A/B$ of $C$ is isomorphic to a group **of Lie type of exactly the same type, but defined over a smaller field**. Moreover, if $G$ is defined over the field $K$ and $A/B$ is defined over the field $K_0$, then $|K_0|^{|\alpha|} = |K|$.*

So, for example: if $G$ is of type $^2B_2(q)$, then the section $A/B$ is of type $^2B_2(q_0)$, for some $q_0 = q^{1/k}$. But the section of a twisted group should not give rise to an untwisted group and the only parameter that is allowed to change is the underlying field. So, in particular,  the (twisted and) untwisted ranks remain the same.

Claim 2 is not so difficult to believe if the group $G$ is untwisted: the fixed points in the root subgroups will generate (up to an isomorphism) a group of exactly the same type (in the sense above) over the field $K_0$ that is fixed by (a conjugate of) the field automorphism, which necessarily satisfies $\lvert K\rvert = \lvert K_0\rvert^{\lvert\alpha\rvert}$. I was unable to find any version of Claim 2 in Steinberg's lecture notes, Carter's book (Simple groups of Lie type), or Gorenstein–Lyons–Solomon (Volume 3), but it is always possible I have overlooked such a statement.

Comment: Is it obvious, or just an enumeration, that a diagram automorphism can never be of order coprime to the group order?

Comment: What do you mean by "automorphism of $G$ coprime order"? do you mean, of order coprime to $|G|$?

Comment: @YCor : Indeed, an automorphism of coprime order is an automorphism the order of which is coprime to the order of the underlying group.

Comment: @LSpice : Automorphisms of the diagram have order 1, 2, or 3. I suspect that you are not counting the trivial automorphism of order 1. By the theorem of Feit-Thompson, every finite simple group has even order. According to the classification, the Suzuki groups (the family, not the sporadic group) are the only groups with an order that is *not* divisible by 3. But the latter do not admit a diagram automorphism of order 3.

Comment: In Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon volume 3, Proposition 4.9.1 addresses many of the issues in Claim 2, although only for $\alpha$ of prime order. To be sure, some additional reasoning is needed to obtain Claim 2 completely. The claim is true with $B=1$, by the way. Parts (a), (b), (c), and (d) of the proposition are relevant.

Comment: One may also specify that $A$ is the subgroup of $C$ generated by all its $r$-elements (where $r$ is the characteristic of the underlying fields); that $C_C(A)=1$; and that every element of $C$ induces an inner-diagonal automorphism on $A$.

Comment: @RichardLyons : thank you for both comments.

Were you just being modest when you said that some additional reasoning was still needed to derive claim 2 from the proposition? It now looks to me like a simple induction on the number of prime divisors of $|\alpha|$ (counted with multiplicity) would do (by starting in the adjoint set-up). Apart from your proposition and your comments, no additional theory (on finite groups of Lie type or of algebraic groups) would be required.

Comment: @user203598: I agree that the additional argument is straightforward.